# Laravel Upsert with Soft Deleted Model

Tags: sql, laravel, upsert

I've got a model that includes a lot of voters, which have soft deletes enabled on them. When I get a new electoral register and list of voters, I want to upload these, and bulk upsert() using Laravel's new functionality.

To do this, I delete (i.e. soft delete) all the voters in the ward, then take them back out (with trashed models) and upsert them. I expected that this would:

- Simply un-delete any voter who was also there in the last uploaded electoral register, and who hadn't changed name at their address.
- Anyone who has moved or died since the last electoral register would just remain soft deleted through the first line.
- Anyone who has moved into a house in the ward will simply be inserted.

But this isn't actually what happens. Instead, what happens is every user is always re-inserted. If I upload the same file twice without making any change to the SQL database, I expect all the lines to be in exactly the same state they were before - with no deleted_at entry. But this isn't the case. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Voter::where('ward_id', $wardID)->delete();

    foreach ($array as $id => $line)
    {
        $upsertArray[] = [
            'address_id' => $line['address_id'],
            'council_id' => $this->id,
            'road_id'    => $roadsArray[$line['parsed_address_road']],
            'ward_id'    => $wardID,
            'forename'   => $line['Elector Forename'],
            'surname'    => $line['Elector Surname'],
            'deleted_at' => null,
        ];
    }

    $results = [];

    foreach (array_chunk($upsertArray, 500) as $upsertArrayChunk)
    {
        $results[] = Voter::withTrashed()->upsert($upsertArrayChunk, ['address_id', 'council_id', 'road_id', 'ward_id', 'forename', 'surname'], ['deleted_at']);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)

> All databases systems except SQL Server require the columns in the second argument provided to the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index.

So you should limit your second argument to the IDs `['address_id', 'council_id', 'road_id', 'ward_id']` and create a unique index on them in your database.

```
ALTER TABLE `voters` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`address_id`, `council_id`, `road_id`, `ward_id`);
```

Comment: I had to include the forename and surname, but this worked perfectly - thanks for pointing it out, I knew it'd be something simple!